# Adding elements to the char array in a struct

Tags: arrays, c, file, struct

The code I write is a program that reads and performs commands line by line from commands.txt. If the program reads a command called ADD 1 SENG101 as an example, it must add student number 1 to the seng101 course. There are these 3 commands in a part of my commands.txt file.

```
ADD 1 SENG101
ADD 1 SENG202
ADD 2 SENG202
```

While I was debugging my program, I noticed that ADD 1 SENG101 is working properly, but while executing the following command, I encounter a problem like this.

[Before SENG202 is added to the courses taken by the student:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jHBBu.png)

[After SENG202 is added to the courses taken by the student:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UsYFb.png)

As you can see from the tip of my mouse, the lesson that needs to be added is "SSENG202" even though it is "SENG202".

The part of my code that does the "ADD" process:

```
else if (0 == strcmp("ADD", word1))
            {
                course_valid = 0;
                lecturer_valid = 0;
                student_valid = 0;
                lecturer_course_load = 0;
                student_course_load = 0;
                student_taken_credits = 0;
                who_is_taught = 0;
                is_student_member_of_course = 0;

                for (i = 0; i < number_of_courses; i++)
                {
                    if (0 == strcmp(course[i].courseCode, word3))
                    {
                        course_valid = 1;                                           //It was checked whether there was a course with the specified course name.
                        break;
                    }                                                               
                }
                for (j = 0; j < number_of_students; j++)
                {
                    if (0 == strcmp(student[j].studentNumber, word2))
                    {
                        student_valid = 1;                                                 //It was checked whether there was a student with the specified name.  
                        if (student[j].number_of_taken_courses < STUDENT_COURSE_LOAD)
                        {
                            student_course_load = 1;                                    //The number of courses the specified student took was checked.                            
                        }   
                        if (student[j].taken_credits < STUDENT_MAX_CREDITS)
                        {
                            student_taken_credits = 1;                              //The total course credits of the specified student were checked.
                        }
                        break;
                    }            
                }

                fprintf(foutput, "%s %s \n%s", "Command: ", readed, "Result: \n");

                if (student_taken_credits && student_course_load && student_valid && course_valid)
                {
                    strcpy(&student[j].taken_courses[student[j].number_of_taken_courses], word3);                  //The specified course was added to the courses taken by the student.
                    student[j].number_of_taken_courses++;                                                  //The number of courses taken by the student has been increased.
                    
                    strcpy(&course[i].who_is_taked[course[i].number_of_taked_students], word2);                 //The specified student has been added to the specified lesson.
                    course[i].number_of_taked_students++;
                    student[j].taken_credits += course[i].courseCredit;
                }
                else if (1 != (student_taken_credits && student_course_load && student_valid && course_valid))
                {
                    fprintf(foutput, "Error!\n");
                    break;
                }
                
                fprintf(foutput, "\n");
            }
```

And if you need all my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "stdlib.h"
#include <stdbool.h>

#pragma warning (disable:4996)
#define MAXCHAR 100
#define TEACHER_COURSE_LOAD 5
#define STUDENT_COURSE_LOAD 8
#define STUDENT_MAX_CREDITS 22

struct students {
    char studentNumber[50];
    char studentName[50];
    char studentSurname[50];
    char taken_courses[50];
    int number_of_taken_courses;
    int taken_credits;
};
struct courses {
    char courseCode[10];
    char courseName[50];
    int courseCredit;
    char who_is_taked[100];
    char who_is_taught[100];
    int number_of_taked_students;
};
struct lecturers {
    char regNumber[10];
    char regSurname[50];
    char regName[50];
    char courses_taught[50];
    int number_of_courses_taught;
};

/*
        PLEASE SEND ARGUMENTS IN THE FOLLOWING ORDER TO THE PROGRAM
        Ex: C:>DBMS students.txt lecturers.txt courses.txt commands.txt output.txt
*/

int main()
{
    int number_of_students = -1;
    int number_of_lecturers = -1;
    int number_of_courses = -1;

    char readed[MAXCHAR];
    char word1[100];
    char word2[100];
    char word3[100];

    FILE* fstudent = fopen("C:\\Users\\ayber\\Desktop\\Files\\students.txt", "r"); // "r" for read
    FILE* flecturers = fopen("C:\\Users\\ayber\\Desktop\\Files\\lecturers.txt", "r"); // "r" for read
    FILE* fcourses = fopen("C:\\Users\\ayber\\Desktop\\Files\\courses.txt", "r"); // "r" for read
    FILE* fcommands = fopen("C:\\Users\\ayber\\Desktop\\Files\\commands.txt", "r"); // "r" for read
    FILE* foutput = fopen("C:\\Users\\ayber\\Desktop\\Files\\output.txt", "a+"); // "a+" for append

    while (fgets(readed, MAXCHAR, fstudent) != NULL)
    {
        number_of_students++;                                                                   //Number of students has been founded!
    }

    struct students* student = malloc(number_of_students * sizeof(struct students));            //Memory allocated for number_of_students students!

    rewind(fstudent);                                                                           //File refreshed for re-read!

    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int k = 0;

    while (fgets(readed, MAXCHAR, fstudent) != NULL)
    {
        readed[strcspn(readed, "\n")] = 0;
        if (sscanf(readed, "%s %s %s", word1, word2, word3) == 3)
        {
            strcpy(student[i].studentNumber, word1);
            strcpy(student[i].studentName, word2);                                              //All students in the file are assigned to the required variables.
            strcpy(student[i].studentSurname, word3);
            student[i].number_of_taken_courses = 0;
            student[i].taken_credits = 0;
            i++;
        }
    }

    while (fgets(readed, MAXCHAR, flecturers) != NULL)
    {
        number_of_lecturers++;                                                                  //Number of lecturers has been founded!
    }

    struct lecturers* lecturer = malloc(number_of_lecturers * sizeof(struct lecturers));        //Memory allocated for number_of_lecturers lecturers!

    rewind(flecturers);           //File refreshed for re-read!

    i = 0;

    while (fgets(readed, MAXCHAR, flecturers) != NULL)
    {
        readed[strcspn(readed, "\n")] = 0;
        if (sscanf(readed, "%s %s %s", word1, word2, word3) == 3)
        {
            strcpy(lecturer[i].regNumber, word1);
            strcpy(lecturer[i].regSurname, word2);                                              //All lecturers in the file are assigned to the required variables.
            strcpy(lecturer[i].regName, word3);
            lecturer[i].number_of_courses_taught = 0;
            i++;
        }
    }

    while (fgets(readed, MAXCHAR, fcourses) != NULL)
    {
        number_of_courses++;                                                                    //Number of courses number has been founded!
    }

    struct courses* course = malloc(number_of_courses * sizeof(struct courses));                //Memory allocated for number_of_courses courses!

    rewind(fcourses);                                                                           //File refreshed for re-read!

    i = 0;

    while (fgets(readed, MAXCHAR, fcourses) != NULL)
    {
        readed[strcspn(readed, "\n")] = 0;
        if (sscanf(readed, "%s %s %s", word1, word2, word3) == 3)
        {
            strcpy(course[i].courseCode, word1);
            strcpy(course[i].courseName, word2);                                                //All courses in the file are assigned to the required variables.
            course[i].courseCredit = atoi(word3);
            strcpy(course[i].who_is_taught, " ");
            course[i].number_of_taked_students = 0;
            i++;
        }
    }

    bool course_valid;
    bool lecturer_valid;
    bool student_valid;
    bool lecturer_course_load;
    bool student_course_load;
    bool student_taken_credits;
    bool who_is_taught;
    bool is_student_member_of_course;


    while (fgets(readed, MAXCHAR, fcommands) != NULL)                                           //STARTED TO READ COMMANDS.TXT
    {
        readed[strcspn(readed, "\n")] = 0;

        if (sscanf(readed, "%s %s %s", word1, word2, word3) == 3)
        {
            if (0 == strcmp("ASSIGN", word1))
            {
                course_valid = 0;
                lecturer_valid = 0;
                student_valid = 0;
                lecturer_course_load = 0;
                student_course_load = 0;
                student_taken_credits = 0;
                who_is_taught = 0;
                is_student_member_of_course = 0;

                for (i = 0; i < number_of_courses; i++)
                {
                    if (0 == strcmp(course[i].courseCode, word3))
                    {
                        course_valid = 1;  
                        if (0 == strcmp(course[i].who_is_taught, " "))              //It was checked whether the name of the course and the person who is 
                        {                                                           //currently teaching the course.
                            who_is_taught = 1;
                        }
                        break;
                    }                    
                }
                for (j = 0; j < number_of_lecturers; i++)
                {
                    if (0 == strcmp(lecturer[j].regNumber, word2))
                    {
                        lecturer_valid = 1;   
                        if (lecturer[j].number_of_courses_taught < TEACHER_COURSE_LOAD)      //The teacher's validation and the course load of the teacher was checked.
                        {
                            lecturer_course_load = 1;
                        }
                        break;
                    }                    
                }

                fprintf(foutput, "%s %s \n%s", "Command: ", readed, "Result: \n");
                
                if (lecturer_course_load && lecturer_valid && course_valid && who_is_taught)
                {
                    strcpy(&lecturer[j].courses_taught[lecturer[j].number_of_courses_taught], word3);                  //The specified course was added to the courses given by the teacher
                    lecturer[j].number_of_courses_taught++;                         //The number of lectures given by the teacher has been increased.
                    
                    if (0 == strcmp(course[i].courseCode, word3))
                    {
                        strcpy(course[i].who_is_taught, word2);                 //The specified teacher has been appointed to the specified lesson.          
                    }
                }
                else if (1 != (lecturer_course_load && lecturer_valid && course_valid && who_is_taught))
                {
                    fprintf(foutput, "Error!\n");
                }
                fprintf(foutput, "\n");
            }
            else if (0 == strcmp("ADD", word1))
            {
                course_valid = 0;
                lecturer_valid = 0;
                student_valid = 0;
                lecturer_course_load = 0;
                student_course_load = 0;
                student_taken_credits = 0;
                who_is_taught = 0;
                is_student_member_of_course = 0;

                for (i = 0; i < number_of_courses; i++)
                {
                    if (0 == strcmp(course[i].courseCode, word3))
                    {
                        course_valid = 1;                                           //It was checked whether there was a course with the specified course name.
                        break;
                    }                                                               
                }
                for (j = 0; j < number_of_students; j++)
                {
                    if (0 == strcmp(student[j].studentNumber, word2))
                    {
                        student_valid = 1;                                                 //It was checked whether there was a student with the specified name.  
                        if (student[j].number_of_taken_courses < STUDENT_COURSE_LOAD)
                        {
                            student_course_load = 1;                                    //The number of courses the specified student took was checked.                            
                        }   
                        if (student[j].taken_credits < STUDENT_MAX_CREDITS)
                        {
                            student_taken_credits = 1;                              //The total course credits of the specified student were checked.
                        }
                        break;
                    }            
                }

                fprintf(foutput, "%s %s \n%s", "Command: ", readed, "Result: \n");

                if (student_taken_credits && student_course_load && student_valid && course_valid)
                {
                    strcpy(&student[j].taken_courses[student[j].number_of_taken_courses], word3);                  //The specified course was added to the courses taken by the student.
                    student[j].number_of_taken_courses++;                                                  //The number of courses taken by the student has been increased.
                    
                    strcpy(&course[i].who_is_taked[course[i].number_of_taked_students], word2);                 //The specified student has been added to the specified lesson.
                    course[i].number_of_taked_students++;
                    student[j].taken_credits += course[i].courseCredit;
                }
                else if (1 != (student_taken_credits && student_course_load && student_valid && course_valid))
                {
                    fprintf(foutput, "Error!\n");
                    break;
                }
                
                fprintf(foutput, "\n");
            }
            else if (0 == strcmp("DROP", word1))
            {
                course_valid = 0;
                lecturer_valid = 0;
                student_valid = 0;
                lecturer_course_load = 0;
                student_course_load = 0;
                student_taken_credits = 0;
                who_is_taught = 0;      
                is_student_member_of_course = 0;

                for (i = 0; i < number_of_courses; i++)
                {
                    if (0 == strcmp(course[i].courseCode, word3))
                    {
                        course_valid = 1;                                           //It was checked whether there was a course with the specified course name.
                    }
                }
                for (i = 0; i < number_of_students; i++)
                {
                    if (0 == strcmp(student[i].studentNumber, word2))
                    {
                        student_valid = 1;                                                //It was checked whether there was a student with the specified name.
                    }
                    for (j = 0; j < number_of_courses; j++)
                    {
                        if (0 == strcmp(&student[i].taken_courses[j], word3))
                        {
                            is_student_member_of_course = 1;                                    //It was checked whether the student took the course or not.
                        }
                    }                    
                }
                fprintf(foutput, "%s %s \n%s", "Command: ", readed, "Result: \n");
          
                if ((student_valid && course_valid) && (is_student_member_of_course !=0))
                {
                    for (i = 0; i < number_of_courses; i++)
                    {
                        if (0 == strcmp(course[i].courseCode, word3))
                        {
                            for (j = 0; j < number_of_students; j++)
                            {
                                if (0 == strcmp(student[j].studentNumber, word2))
                                {
                                    for (k = 0; k < student[j].number_of_taken_courses; k++)
                                    {
                                        if (0 == strcmp(&student[j].taken_courses[k], word3))
                                        {
                                            student[j].taken_courses[k] = 0;
                                            student[j].taken_credits -= course[i].courseCredit;
                                            student[j].number_of_taken_courses--;
                                        }
                                    }
                                    for (k = 0; k < course[i].number_of_taked_students; k++)
                                    {
                                        if (0 == strcmp(&course[i].who_is_taked[k], word2))
                                        {
                                            course[i].who_is_taked[k] = 0;
                                            course[i].number_of_taked_students--;
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                else if (1 != ((student_valid && course_valid) && (is_student_member_of_course != 0)))
                {
                    fprintf(foutput, "Error!\n");
                }
                fprintf(foutput, "\n");
            }
        }
        else if (sscanf(readed, "%s %s", word1, word2) == 2)
        {
            if (0 == strcmp("LIST4", word1))
            {
                course_valid = 0;
                lecturer_valid = 0;
                student_valid = 0;
                lecturer_course_load = 0;
                student_course_load = 0;
                student_taken_credits = 0;
                who_is_taught = 0;
                is_student_member_of_course = 0;

                for (i = 0; i < number_of_students; i++)
                {
                    if (0 == strcmp(student[i].studentNumber, word2))
                    {
                        student_valid = 1;                                               //It was checked whether there was a student with the specified name.
                        break;
                    }
                }

                for (j = 0; j < student[i].number_of_taken_courses; j++)
                {         
                    for (k = 0; k < number_of_courses; k++)
                    {
                        if (0 == strcmp(&student[i].taken_courses[j], course[k].courseCode))
                        {
                            is_student_member_of_course = 1;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }

                fprintf(foutput, "%s %s \n%s", "Command: ", readed, "Result: \n");

                if (student_valid && is_student_member_of_course)
                {
                    fprintf(foutput,"Student : %s - %s %s\n", student[i].studentNumber, student[i].studentName, student[i].studentSurname);
                    fprintf(foutput, "Participating Courses : %d\n",student[i].number_of_taken_courses);
                    for (k = 0; k < student[i].number_of_taken_courses; k++)
                    {
                        for (j = 0; j < number_of_courses; j++)
                        {
                            if (0 == strcmp(&student[i].taken_courses[k], course[j].courseCode))
                            {
                                fprintf(foutput, "%s %s %d\n", course[j].courseCode, course[j].courseName, course[j].courseCredit);
                            }
                        }                   
                    }
                    fprintf(foutput, "Achieved Credits: %d\n", student[i].taken_credits);
                }
                else if((student_valid && is_student_member_of_course) != 1)
                {
                    fprintf(foutput, "Error!\n");
                }               

                fprintf(foutput, "\n");
            }
            else if (0 == strcmp("LIST5", word1))
            {
                fprintf(foutput, "%s %s \n%s", "Command: ", readed, "Result: \n");          //The function of LIST5 will be added...
                fprintf(foutput, "\n");
            }
            else if (0 == strcmp("LIST6", word1))
            {
                fprintf(foutput, "%s %s \n%s", "Command: ", readed, "Result: \n");          //The function of LIST6 will be added...
                fprintf(foutput, "\n");
            }
            else if (0 == strcmp("LIST7", word1))
            {
                fprintf(foutput, "%s %s \n%s", "Command: ", readed, "Result: \n");          //The function of LIST7 will be added...
                fprintf(foutput, "\n");
            }
        }
        else if (sscanf(readed, "%s", word1) == 1)
        {
            if (0 == strcmp("LIST1", word1))
            {
                fprintf(foutput, "%s %s \n%s", "Command: ", readed, "Result: \n");          //The function of LIST1 (Working Propery)
                for (i = 0; i < number_of_students; i++)
                {
                    fprintf(foutput, "%s %s %s", student[i].studentNumber, student[i].studentName, student[i].studentSurname);
                    fprintf(foutput, "\n");
                }
                fprintf(foutput, "\n");
            }
            else if (0 == strcmp("LIST2", word1))                                           //The function of LIST2 (Working Propery) 
            {
                fprintf(foutput, "%s %s \n%s", "Command: ", readed, "Result: \n");
                for (i = 0; i < number_of_lecturers; i++)
                {
                    fprintf(foutput, "%s %s %s", lecturer[i].regNumber, lecturer[i].regName, lecturer[i].regSurname);
                    fprintf(foutput, "\n");
                }
                fprintf(foutput, "\n");
            }
            else if (0 == strcmp("LIST3", word1))
            {
                fprintf(foutput, "%s %s \n%s", "Command: ", readed, "Result: \n");           //The function of LIST3 (Working Propery)
                for (i = 0; i < number_of_courses; i++)
                {
                    fprintf(foutput, "%s %s %d", course[i].courseCode, course[i].courseName, course[i].courseCredit);
                    fprintf(foutput, "\n");
                }
                fprintf(foutput, "\n");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Error\n");
            // ERROR
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Please can you help me about fixing this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you problem is here

```
struct students {
    char studentNumber[50];
    char studentName[50];
    char studentSurname[50];
    char taken_courses[50];   <---------- Can only save one string/name
    int number_of_taken_courses;
    int taken_credits;
};
```

but here

```
strcpy(&student[j].taken_courses[student[j].number_of_taken_courses], word3);
student[j].number_of_taken_courses++;
```

it seems that you try to save multiple names in `taken_courses`.

Maybe you really want:

```
struct students {
    char studentNumber[50];
    char studentName[50];
    char studentSurname[50];
    char taken_courses[MAX_NUM_COURSES][50];
    int number_of_taken_courses;
    int taken_credits;
};
```

and updates to the `strcpy` accordingly.